# Reading both attributes and nodes at the same time in Kettle / Spoon

Tags: xml, kettle

I'm using kettle and trying to load both the attribute and node values from an xml document.

```
<Colors>
  <Color code="123">blue</Color>
  <Color code="234">black</Color>
  <Color code="456">green</Color>
</Colors>
```

If I set the loop XPath to Colors I will only get one row but it will read both the code and the value.
example:

```
Code  | Color
123   | blue
```

But if I set the XPath to the Color I will get 3 rows, but it will not read the value for each item.
example:

```
Code 
123
234
456
```

How do I read all elements and both the attribute and node value in one pass?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a "Get Data From XML step" (input category)
Set the Loop XPath to `/Colors/Color`
In the fields tab, hit "Get Fields". This will add a row for

```
Name    XPath   Element Type    Format  Length  Precision   CurrencyDecimal Group   Trim type   Repeat
code    @code   Node    Integer                         none    N
```

Now, for the value of the elements, add a new row manually in the grid like this:

```
Name    XPath   Element Type    Format  Length  Precision   CurrencyDecimal Group   Trim type   Repeat
value   text()  Node    String                          none    N
```

In other words, use the XPath standard `text()` function to extract the text content from the context node.

As always, use Preview rows to check the result. I get this:

```
code    value
123 blue
234 black
456 green
```

Comment: Thanks a ton!  That's been making me mad.

Comment: np, glad that helped. There are a few nasties with generating XML elements with both attributes and text content as well.